# How to assert canvas element in protractor tests

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, protractor

Is it possible to assert on the object inside the HTML5 `<canvas>` element with the Protractor tool? I can do click, drag and drop action over the element using 
co-ordinates, but I need to assert the `<canvas>` element.

Comment: That the `<canvas>` element exists or ???

Comment: Yes <canvas> element exists. I need validate some elements (ex: text) inside the canvas element.

Answer (score 1):

The `<canvas>` element is like an applet inside the page. You can detect that the element exists but you will not be able to see inside it with Selenium. If dev adds hooks inside the `<canvas>` element, you can add JS calls to your script using `JavascriptExecutor` to "see" into the `<canvas>` tag, manipulate it, etc. but that will rely on the hooks that are added.